# Liferay with ssl redirect loop on c/portal/login?p_l_id=10727

Tags: ssl, liferay

I try configure ssl to liferay portal. in portal-ext.properties is:

```
web.server.https.port=443
company.security.auth.requires.https=true
web.server.protocol=https
```

everything works, but when I click on login, i have redirect loop on /c/portal/login?p_l_id=10727

i can sign in portal when browse link https://localhost/home?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&saveLastPath=false&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin

any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Monitor the requests and check what URLs are redirected to what other URLs, post them here (use Firebug or equivalent tools). Make sure no caching is going on.

Comment: Hi Karci, I am also getting the same issue when using with https, after login it goes on redirect loop for just this url /c/portal/login. did you got any solution ? I am not finding any useful info so far.

Comment: i didn´t find solution, I create filter where is just redirect to PortalUtil.getHomeURL(request) + "?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&saveLastPath=false&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin"